# Null pointer exception - loading a new activity from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, parse-platform

I ran into a null pointer exception when trying to load a new activity from a fragment - it essentially tells me an unexpected error has occurred. Below is the log cat message:

```
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 1245
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dooba.beta/com.dooba.beta.matchOptionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at com.dooba.beta.matchOptionActivity.onCreate(matchOptionActivity.java:29)
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     ... 11 more
```

Below is the fragment activity code (the place where the new intent activity is called)

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Distance");
    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setConversationsList();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);
        Button newPage = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnMatchConfirm);
        newPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), matchOptionActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

private void setConversationsList() {
    currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

    //  query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
    query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
    // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
    query.setLimit(1);
    query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
   // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
   // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
    query.orderByDescending("Name");




    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

        public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                    names.add(userList.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                    names.add(userList.get(i).get("Headline").toString());



                        names.add(userList.get(i).get("Age").toString());
                        names.add(userList.get(i).get("ActivityName").toString());


                    //       names.add(userList.get(i).getParseObject("ProfilePicture").;


                }




                usersListView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistview1);
                namesArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                        openConversation(names, i);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error loading user list",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error finding that user",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Below is the code for the matchOption activity (the activity that is called upon button click)

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.matchoption);

        final ImageView idrinks = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.icasual);
        idrinks.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                matchOptionActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(matchOptionActivity.this, MessagingActivity.class));
            }
        });


}
}
```

Furthermore, I am using Parse to populate my list of users, and I would like to know how I would be hide the confirm button in the event that the list is empty.

Thanks in advance.

Update
below is the fragment XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_bac3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/userlistview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" 
        android:divider="@null"

        >
        </ListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMatchConfirm"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gray_bac"
            android:layout_below="@+id/userlistview1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:text="Confirm" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Indicate the line `08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at com.dooba.beta.matchOptionActivity.onCreate(matchOptionActivity.java:29)`

Comment: @GeorgeD - if he wouldnt have the exception would have been ActivityNotFound with have you forgotten to declare it in the manifest.

Comment: @user3827788 are u sure you have the xml containing an imageview with the same id you specified ?

Comment: as per logcat error is in matchOptionActivity.java but your code havent any problem as per guessing your id of imageview is not present in XML hope so this is the case am not sure please chek it out

Comment: Thank you for your prompt responses. I have added the XML under the update section of my initial post for further clarification

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to change the code

**from this**

```
idrinks.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                matchOptionActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(matchOptionActivity.this, MessagingActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

**to this**

```
idrinks.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent i = new Intent(this,MessagingActivity.class); 
               i.startActivity(new Intent(matchOptionActivity.this, MessagingActivity.class));
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputation to add comment...Can you also provide the matchoption xml for further analysis or check the onClick() method. looks like some issue over there

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 11:57:14.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at com.dooba.beta.matchOptionActivity.onCreate(matchOptionActivity.java:29)